# SpriteKit: textureFromNode method not working in initWithSize method

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

This doesn't work – the `newNode`'s texture is `nil`:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor orangeColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

        SKTexture *texture = [self.view textureFromNode:node];            
        SKSpriteNode *newNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
        [self addChild:newNode];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This does work:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor orangeColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

        SKAction *createNewNode = [SKAction runBlock:^{
            SKTexture *texture = [self.view textureFromNode:node];            
            SKSpriteNode *newNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
            [self addChild:newNode];
        }];

        [self runAction: createNewNode];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Can someone please explain why!? Thanks!

---

In case you're wondering why the `node` is not added the scene: The Apple documentation for `textureFromNode` states: "The node being rendered does not need to appear in the view’s presented scene."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is: at the point where you are creating the sprite node (inside the scene's `initWithSize:`) the node graph is not fully set up yet. The scene isn't connected with (presented by) the view, and therefore it is not set up for rendering.

It's quite possible that SKSpriteNode textures for sprites using a color are only created after the scene is presented. This would explain why running the block action works.

You can probably fix this also by simply moving the code from `initWithSize:` to the scene's `didMoveToView` method, which is called after the scene was presented on the view.

Comment: After moving the code to the didMoveToView method, the code worked. Thanks! Regarding the node's texture: It didn't make a difference whether I used a solid color or a regular PNG texture for the `SKSpriteNode` in the `initWithSize:` method.